# Extjs checkboxes inside basic form

Tags: extjs, checkbox, extjs3

I have a basic form inside a window. This form has several check boxes and I need to some how be able to select all with another checkbox. How am I supposed to access these checkbox types. I am trying to get reference to "this" and then this.getForm().getFieldValues() but is there a better way to do it, as I only need to get the checkboxes and not other fields.

Thanks,
SS

Comment: A working showcase (http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_Forum_Help#Posting_a_working_showcase) would go a long way to helping us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default ExtJs fields don't have a **getForm()** method to get access to their parent. However, you can use [this override](http://www.lustforge.com/2011/06/19/extjs-field-getform-override/) to add this method. Once you've got the form, you can get access to any field you like, which should let you do what you describe.